# How to select id's from one table and insert/update to another table

Tags: python, mysql, backtrader

I am working on an automated trading system in python, I have set up a database which inserts a row every time a new order is generated.

What I am having trouble with is if the order is successful I would like to add the OrderID to my Position Table.

**Here are the scenarios that could happen**

if there is no open reference with the same `OrderID, AccountID, strategyID, AssetID` then the insert new row where `PositionID=NUM, OpenReference=OrderID, CloseReference=NULL, Status=2`

if there are positions that are not of `status(3)` existing check to see if it matches the OpenReference parameters(`OrderID, AccountID, strategyID, AssetID`) if it does update the `OrderID` to column `CloseReference` and update `status=3`.

**Order Table Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE `__order` (
  `OrderID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AccountID` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `StrategyID` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `AssetID` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `TimeSubmitted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Action` mediumtext,
  `Type` mediumtext,
  `Price` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Quantity` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `Outstanding` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `TimeCompleted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Commission` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrderID`),
  KEY `AssetID_FORK_idx` (`AssetID`),
  KEY `AccountID_FORK_idx` (`AccountID`),
  KEY `StratID_FORK_idx` (`StrategyID`),
  CONSTRAINT `AccountID_FORK` FOREIGN KEY (`AccountID`) REFERENCES `__account` (`AccountID`),
  CONSTRAINT `AssetID_FORK` FOREIGN KEY (`AssetID`) REFERENCES `__asset` (`AssetID`),
  CONSTRAINT `StratID_FORK` FOREIGN KEY (`StrategyID`) REFERENCES `__strategy` (`StrategyID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=577 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

**Position Table Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE `__position` (
  `PositionID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `OpenReference` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `CloseReference` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PositionID`),
  KEY `BuyReference_order_FK_idx` (`OpenReference`),
  KEY `SellReference_order_FK_idx` (`CloseReference`),
  KEY `Status_order_FK_idx` (`Status`),
  CONSTRAINT `BuyReference_order_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`OpenReference`) REFERENCES `__order` (`OrderID`),
  CONSTRAINT `SellReference_order_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`CloseReference`) REFERENCES `__order` (`OrderID`),
  CONSTRAINT `Status_order_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`Status`) REFERENCES `__status` (`StatusID`)
)
```

**My Python Code**

```
def insert_position(self, openRef=None, status=None):
    return self.execute(
        sql="""
            INSERT INTO __position
                (OpenReference, Status) 
            VALUES 
                (%s, %s);""",
        params=(openRef, status,))

def update_position(self, positionID, closeRef=None, status=None):
    return self.execute(
        sql="""
            UPDATE __position
                SET CloseReference = %s,
                    Status = %s
            WHERE PositionID = %s;""", params=(closeRef, status, positionID,))
```

Comment: Do a `SELECT` query to see if there's a row that meets the condition. If there is, execute an `UPDATE` query, otherwise execute the `INSERT` query.

Comment: @Barmar I see, please look at the revised question.

Comment: How is the `Position` table related to the `Order` table?

Comment: What is `NUM`, and why isn't it a parameter to `insert_position`? Or is `PositionID` an auto-increment ID?

Comment: `OpenRef` and `CloseRef` are foreign keys to `Order.OrderID`?

Comment: Isn't `OrderID` a primary key? Can it have the same OrderID but different AccountID, strategyID, AssetID?

Comment: The __position table is related based on the foreign keys OpenRefernce and ClosedReference. The OrderID is a primary key to the __order Table.  AccountID, strategyID, AssetID must match the OpenReference values. if it doesn't match must be related to another __position row.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a `SELECT` query to check if there are any positions with the given order ID.

If there are, update all the ones with `status != 3` as required. If not, insert the new row.

```
def insert_or_update_position(self, order_id):
    self.execute(sql = "SELECT 1 FROM __position WHERE OpenReference = %s LIMIT 1", (order_id,))
    row = self.cursor.fetchone()
    if row:
        self.execute(sql="""
            UPDATE __position
            SET CloseReference = %s, Status = 3
            WHERE OpenReference = %s AND Status != 3""", (order_id, order_id))
    else:
        return self.execute(sql="""
            INSERT INTO __position (OpenReference, Status)
            VALUES (%s, 2)""", (order_id,))
```